# Merging on json files in java

Tags: java, json

I have 2 json files.

JsonFile 1 looks like this:

```
{"SearchResults": [{"Source": "Indianexpress.com", "Title":"ABC","Summary":"Test"}]}
```

Json File 2 looks like the same as above.

```
{"SearchResults": [{"Source": "Hindu.com", "Title":"XYZ","Summary":"TestABC"}]}
```

I have to merge these two files in such a way that the Json should be like below.

```
{"SearchResults": [{"Source": "Indianexpress.com", "Title":"ABC","Summary":"Test"},{"Source": "Hindu.com", "Title":"XYZ","Summary":"TestABC"}]}
```

Please suggest me how to achieve this in java

Comment: Can you confirm you're working with java? (the tag should make it clear, but people sometimes confuse java and javascript...). If so, are you already using any library such as Jackson or Gson to parse the JSON, or are you simply handling it as a string so far?

Comment: By A) learning how a JSON parser works (gson, jackson) to then B) use such a parser to read that data into memory C) followed by a "merge" in memory to D) finally write the merged content back into a file. Sorry, but your question is basically way too broad. We help you when you have specific questions regarding the different steps, but we are not going to draw the map for you, and write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
   String json1 = "{\"SearchResults\": [{\"Source\": \"Indianexpress.com\", \"Title\":\"ABC\",\"Summary\":\"Test\"}]}";
   String json2 = "....";
   JSONObject jsonOb1 = new JSONObject(json1);
   JSONObject jsonOb2 = new JSONObject(json2);
   JSONArray innerArray1 = jsonOb1.getJSONArray("SearchResults");
   JSONArray innerArray2 = jsonOb2.getJSONArray("SearchResults");
   for(int i = 0; i < innerArray2.length(); i++)
   {
        innerArray1.put(innerArray2.getJSONObject(i);
   }
```

And here you go, jsonOb1 contains the merged information. You can further stringify it using `.toString()` method.

This method requires org.json lib, some tutorial for this lib : https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json